# How to initialize the pointer with the variadic-template?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

How to correctly assign a pointer with the variadic template.

I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void init() { cerr << "EMPTY" << endl; }

template <typename A, typename ...B> void init(A argHead, B... argTail) 
{
    argHead = new bool;
    *(argHead) = true;
    init(argTail...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    bool *a1,*a2;
    init(a1,a2);
    std::cout << (*a1) << " " << (*a2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with variadic templates, or indeed templates at all. Please reduce your problem to the minimum possible before posting.

Comment: Also that's not initialisation; it is assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the variadic-args by reference:

```
template <typename A, typename ...B> void init(A& argHead, B&... argTail)
//                                             ^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    argHead = new bool{true};
    init(argTail...);
}
```

Or pass the `reference_wrapper` to the args using [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

```
#include <functional>  // std::ref

int main()
{
    bool* a1, * a2;
    init(std::ref(a1), std::ref(a2));
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)  you can use *[fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)* like:

```
template <typename... Args> void init(Args&... args) 
{
    ((args = new bool{ true }), ...);
}
```

---

As *@LightnessRacesinOrbit* mentioned in the comments, the args undergoes assignment, not the initialization.